# Salesforce Marketing Cloud - Unable to pass value to data extension though landing page

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, landing-page

I have a survey landing page which I am trying to add values through survey and store them in data extension. I am using Data Manager for this, when I am submitting the form it gives an error - Unable to update the data extension.
Can you help me figure out what could be the root cause?

The field I am trying to update is "RedesSociales"  which I have also added in html form.

*Script:*

```
%%[
var @EmailAddress, @RedesSociales

        set @EmailAddress = QUERYPARAMETER("key")
        set @RedesSociales = RequestParameter("RedesSociales")

       ]%%
```

**Html:**

```
<form action="https://cl.s7.exct.net/DEManager.aspx" name="subscribeForm" method="post" lang="fr">
        <input type="hidden" name="_clientID" value="7328327" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_deExternalKey" value="55A7AF1D-D7B1-4912-8440-CFDD4E807D88" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_action" value="add/update" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_returnXML" value="0" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_successURL" value="someSuccessPage" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_errorURL" value="http://someErrorPage" />

<div class="input-field inline col s12"> 
               <span>1. ¿Usa redes sociales?</span>
              <p>
                <label>
               <input type="checkbox" id="Sí" name= "RedesSociales" value="Sí"/>
               <span>Sí  </span>
                </label>
              </p>
               <div>
                <p>
                <label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="No" name="RedesSociales" value ="No"/>
                <span>No</span>
                </label>
                <p>
            </div>
```

Comment: The form's method is `POST`, but I see that `queryparameter()` is being used which only works with `GET` requests. Try using `RequestParameter()` instead (just as you have done with the `RedesSociales` parameter). I also don't see the `key` parameter being included/passed anywhere... is it required? Will it be a hidden form input?

Comment: @MarkG Actully, I just want to display the email id in the form (prefilled), that's why Queryparameter . And I am trying to display a question with 2 values, which's response I have to capture in DE. The email id itself is the key, which will be already present in DE, I have to update the same record with the responses. Hope this makes sense

Comment: @ShantanuPunekar What's the data type of your RedesSociales field in your DE? Presuming it's "Text"?

Comment: @Macca No, its boolean. I have similar more fields which are text and displayed as checkbox in the landing page.

Comment: I am able to fix this. The problem was with Data Type and html formatting.